# ebay sandbox user cannot sell item

Tags: java, ebay-api

I created eBay sandbox user, but cannot add item. When I call Java API example it tells

> com.ebay.sdk.ApiException: Starting in September, we’re showing buyers estimated delivery times based on the service(s) you selected and your handling time. Learn more at http://pages.ebay.com/sellerinformation/news/shippingservices.html.
>   We're sorry, but before you list an item, you must create a seller's account by submitting a valid credit card through our secure form.
>       at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.getApiException(ApiCall.java:613)

Also I could not sell any item directly from sandbox site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to have a feedbacks on testing account and run

```
<ValidateTestUserRegistrationRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<!-- Standard Input Fields -->
<FeedbackScore>500</FeedbackScore>
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>my token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
</ValidateTestUserRegistrationRequest>
```